# Interval of two dates not output correctly in R

Tags: r, lubridate

Wanted to get the interval between 2 days displayed in days. Using lubridate package.
Method 1 using interval function.

```
library(lubridate)
date1 <- as.Date("2022-08-08")
date2 <- as.Date("2022-09-08")
x <- interval(date1, date2)
print(x)
days(x)
```

Output as follows

```
[1] 2022-08-08 UTC--2022-09-08 UTC
[1] "2678400d 0H 0M 0S"
```

Question: Why the answer is not correct? 2678400 days!

Method 2 using difftime function.

```
y <- difftime(date1, date2, units="days")
print(y)
```

Output as follows

```
Time difference of 31 days
```

The thing is, I want it to display only 31 instead of the whole sentence "Time difference of 31 days"
Need some guidance here.

Comment: Use `as.numeric(difftime("2022-08-08", "2022-09-08", units='day'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lubridate::days()` works with numerics.  You've given it a period.  `as.numeric(x)` gives `2678400` (the number of seconds between 2022-08-08 and 2022-09-08?).  You're a victim of implicit coercion.

@jay.sf has given you the solution for `difftime`.  To get the correct answer using lubridate:

```
time_length(x, "days")
[1] 31
```

@JustJames gave the full explanation of what went wrong in their now-deleted answer:

"According to the docs

as.interval changes difftime, Duration, Period and numeric class objects to intervals that begin at the specified date-time. Numeric objects are first coerced to timespans equal to the numeric value in seconds."

Comment: @JustJames  I hope you are comfortable with my edit.  FWIW, I think deleting your answer was unnecessarily self-censorious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
date1 <- as.Date("2022-08-08")
date2 <- as.Date("2022-09-08")

dateDiff <- as.numeric(difftime(date2, date1))
print(dateDiff)
```

Output

```
> dateDiff = as.numeric(difftime(date2, date1))
> print(dateDiff)
[1] 31
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your first code sample does not use `lubridate`.  `as.Date`, `as.numeric`  and `difftime` are all `base` functions.

Comment: I forgot to delete the library definition as I copied the snippet from the question asked. But anyways, thank you for mentioning. I've edited my post.